# Using np.where in cython as index

Tags: python, numpy, indexing, cython, where-clause

I am trying to use np.where in a cython program to select where values are within a radius. Ususally this would work with numpy, but with cython I get

TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer

```
def test(double[:,::1] array, double[:] point, double radius):
    array = np.asarray(array)
    idx = np.where(np.logical_and(np.greater_equal(array[:, 0], point[0] - radius), np.less_equal(array[:, 0], point[0] + radius)))
    a = array[idx]
```

I tried doing this but got error

only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

`a = array[idx[0].astype(int)]`

Comment: I think you want a = array[idx[0]]

Comment: That gives a TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index.....

because I believe the output is a tuple of arrays. I tried doing     a = array[idx[0].astype(int)] as well

Comment: I'm just getting started with cython, but came to this point because Im working with large np arrays on which i iteratively perform np operations (such as np.where...)- so in the example above np.where is running in cython and therefore faster? Worth the headache to start learning how to use cython instead of pure python?

Answer (score 0):

Strangely it worked to do this even though I already did np.asarray

```
a = np.array(array)[idx[0]]
```